# Make Even Divs Switch Floats

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-selectors

The issue that I am having is that I have a div with id "#flights" as my main container, I have divs with the class ".flight" being the container of each option, and then inside of .flight I have two divs, one for the img and one for the information, and a clear after each like so:

```
<div class="flight">
    <div class="flight-img"></div>
    <div class="flight-heading">
        <h2>Shared Flights</h2>
        <p>The shared flight option is available for 1 to 5 people. This is our most economical flight. You will fly with other passengers that are booked that day.</p>
        <button>Book Now</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

My css for these is:

```
.flight-img {
    background: url(../img/flights.jpg) top left no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 40%;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;

}


.flight-heading {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Everything is working perfectly except I want to have them to switch sides (ie .flight-img to be floated right and .flight-heading to be floated left) on the even children.

I have tried:

```
.flight-img:nth-of-type(2n){
    float: right;
}
```

and it doesn't seem to be working. I've tried putting :nth-child(2n) along with :nth-of-type/child (even).

I am sure I am messing something up but unsure of how to even search for what I'm trying to do in order to find out what.

Edit: Adding

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".flight-img:even").css("float","right");
    });
```

works perfectly, I just cannot seem to get the css ::pseudo classes to work and was hoping not to use jquery/js for this or as little as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is your clear `div`s.  The nth-of-type is based on element type, not the class selector you used, so the clear `<div>`s count as siblings of `.flight`s and children of the `#flights` `<div>`. Ah! took me a minute to figure it out, but 4n-1 should work for you.  Although I should mention that there are other ways to clear the floats.  One way would be to use `overflow:hidden` on the `.flight` `<div>`s.  That way you can just use 2n by taking out the clear `<div>`s.

Comment: This did exactly what I needed. I am gonna have to look into the overflow:hidden and see how it works. Thanks so much! And @kaiido that jfiddle really helped show me how to implement it. Thanks to both of you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the :odd pseudo selector:

in your css:

```
.flight:nth-child(even) .flight-img {
    float:left;
}
.flight:nth-child(even) .flight-heading {
    float:right;
}
```

so the flight-img and flight-heading in every other `.flight` container will be floated left/right respectively

Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried adding both lines and one at a time. Each time it didn't seem to change the position of the divs.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I don't understand well but what about the * selector, something like:

```
<style>
.flight-img {
    background: yellow;/*put a img url*/
    background-size: cover;
    width: 40%;
    height: 400px;
    float: right;
}
.flight-heading {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    top: 50%;
}   
.flight-heading *{
    float: right;
}
</style>
<div class="flight">
  <div class="flight-img"></div>
  <div class="flight-heading">
    <h2>Shared Flights</h2>
    <p>The shared flight option is available for 1 to 5 people. This is our most economical   flight. You will fly with other passengers that are booked that day.</p>
    <button>Book Now</button>
  </div>
</div>
```